# cannot type some characters with mintty

Tags: cygwin, mintty, teamviewer

Using mintty as terminal, running it like this :

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

I cannot type characters like ~,[,{ ...

But I can type all those characters on the windows cmd terminal, and on cygwin default terminal, running cygwin.bat :

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i
```

What's doing mintty on my keyboard ?

*** This is only happening when logged remotely using Teamviewer ***

Comment: I use mintty all the time without issue. What keyboard does your Teamviewer come in with? This feels like a "misconfiguration" when teamviewer is in the middle.

Comment: What you mean by the "cygwin default terminal"? Cygwin's default terminal **is** MinTTY.

Comment: I have a similar issue, except that the keys also don't work in the windows console window running bash either. When I type Ctrl-V and then one of the keys, I notice that they are all prefixed with an ESC character; e.g. the sequence `Ctrl-V` `\ ` results in `^[\ ` (where ESC is displayed as `^[`). Did you find any clue to what the reason may be?

Comment: Oh, I should add that (1) the issue persists even with a shell started  via `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --noprofile --norc --noediting`, which should disable readline and prevents bash from executing (some) startup scripts; and (2) that Windows programs like Notepad++ or cmd display the characters just fine, which seems to indicate a cygwin or bash issue.

Comment: Interesting thing is that if you type the normal key (without modifiers like AltGr) several times and then with the modifier it will print the character you need